# No known instance method for selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm developing an iOS 4 application using latest SDK, **XCode 4.2** and **ARC**.

I've added a method to `appDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;
@class SecondViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController* navController;
    ViewController* viewController;
    SecondViewController* secondViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

- (void) showSecondViewController;

@end
```

And it's implemented in `appDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.title = @"First";
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
}

- (void) showSecondViewController
{
    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondViewController.title = @"Second";
    [navController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

But, when I send a message to that method in ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)goSecondClicked:(id)sender
{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] showSecondViewController];
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

**Automatic Reference Counting Issue
No known instance method for selector 'showSecondViewController'**

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to cast the delegate object that you get as:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then call the method on `appDelegate`

Answer (score 3):

Change your `goSecondClicked` action method to this:

```
- (IBAction)goSecondClicked:(id)sender 
{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:@selector(showSecondViewController)];
}
```

EDIT: although this alternative works for the given situation, it should be noted that the compiler won't help you if you change the method name in your delegate and forget to change the name on the selector call. So, this should be used carefully.

Comment: I really wished that downvoters always explained their reason...Although not the best solution, my answer works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define this macro on your AppDelegate.h

```
#define APP_DELEGATE (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

After this, you can invoke your selector with:

```
[APP_DELEGATE showSecondViewController];
```